# Can't access to server by name or localhost in Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have a docker-compose file as below:

```
version: '2.2'
networks:
  Platform-Network:
    name: IoT-Network
volumes:
  Platform:
  Nginx:
  ...
  ...
services: 
  Platform:
    container_name: node-red
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    expose:
      - "1880"
    networks:
      - Platform-Network
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./node-red:/data
  Nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports: 
      - "4000:80"
    depends_on:
      - Platform
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    restart: always
    networks:
      - Platform-Network
  ...
  ...
```

I use nginx as reverse proxy with this config:

```
user nginx;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 4000;
        listen [::]:4000;
        server_name localhost;
        location / { 
            proxy_pass http://platform:1880; 
            proxy_set_header Host $host; # 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 1200s; 
            proxy_send_timeout 1200s; 
            proxy_read_timeout 1h; 
        }
    }
}
```

I run the docker-compose and containers run,but I can't access to server with IP `localhost:4000` or `127.0.0.1:4000`. Even if I set server_name to anything like `test.com` and I set `test.com:4000` as localhost in `/etc/hosts`, still I can't access to server. Only when I enter Nginx container IP like `172.20.0.5:4000` I can access to the server. what's the problem? I want to access to the server with IP `localhost:4000` or something like `test.com:4000`